# confusion with jquery , ajax post

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post, http-post

I have a simple html page , and by using jquery/ajax , i am trying to send a simple *json* file to my php server.The behavior of my script though is really confusing..

First of all i tried , what i have found on the web(other SO questions) :

### Script1

---

```
var data = {"deviceUUID":"lssfds998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfdsl"};

$.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http://192.138.4.115/Server_CityInfo/register.php",
                         data: data,
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json"
                         }).success(function(response, status, xhr){
                             console.log(response);
                             console.log(status);
                             console.log(xhr);
                        });
```

Script1 , sends an empty (null) json file to my server.

### Script2

---

```
var data = {"deviceUUID":"lssfds998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfdsl"};

$.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http://192.168.4.113/Server_CityInfo/register.php",
                         data: data,
                         //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json"
                         }).success(function(response, status, xhr){
                             console.log(response);
                             console.log(status);
                             console.log(xhr);
                        });
```

In Script2 , where i comment the line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` results are slightly better and on the server side i get something like: `deviceUUID=lssfds998&os=bb&pushToken=l1355436gdfsfdsl`. But still is not in a json form that i need it.

### Script3

---

```
var data = '{"deviceUUID":"lssfds998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfdsl"}';

$.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "http://192.168.4.113/Server_CityInfo/register.php",
                         data: data,
                         //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json"
                         }).success(function(response, status, xhr){
                             console.log(response);
                             console.log(status);
                             console.log(xhr);
                        });
```

In Script3 , my data variable is a string.. As you see , i wrap it inside `' '`. This time , i *DO* get the json correctly on my server.

However even when i comment the `dataType: "json"` line , i also get the json correctly on my server. So whats going on here? I have a feeling , that i cant encode my data to json so in the end i have to do it manually. Is it wrong though? Do i really need to specify a `dataType` and `contentType` in my request? If i just make my data look like a perfectly fine json string , like : `'{"deviceUUID":"lssfds998", "os":"bb", "pushToken":"l1355436gdfsfdsl"}'` and send it without using the aforementioned parameters , is it correct?

For fulfilling purposes this is how my server script looks :

```
// We use php://input to get the raw $_POST results.
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_post = json_decode($json, true);

//creating variables from received json
$deviceUDID = $json_post['deviceUUID'];
$os = $json_post['os'];
$pushToken = $json_post['pushToken'];
```

Comment: -1 for a perfectly fine question , that took me almost 20 minutes to compose and shows a really confusing behavior. If this is not a question that should be asked , what is?

Comment: wtf is going on here? -2 ? For what??? Do you even read the damn question??

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery does an intelligent guess on the content of the request if you don't specify it. In the case of JSON as a string, maybe it just something like `text/html` or `appication/x-www-form-encoded` because it doesn't realize the content is JSON. But why complain about specifying the `dataType` or `contentType` if that solves your problem?

Comment: I dont know if what i am doing is correct , or it will have any problems in the long run. I ve done http post requests using c# , java , obj-c , python etc , in all of them i always specify the data/contentType when attempting the request. So i guess that , this is the way to do it.

Comment: Yes, if this is the only way it works, then it's probably the correct way of doing it. If jQuery or the PHP framework cannot correctly guess the content of the request, you are left with explicitly telling them what it is you're sending.

Comment: Even so , could you guess why it is wrong? There are other examples on the web , where these parameters are used.

Comment: The first 2 examples are not sending JSON, yet that's what you're specifying as your data type.  Send `JSON.stringify(data)` instead to send valid JSON.

Comment: @Archer , you are suggesting to use the "JSON.stringify" method with which one of the 3 scripts?

Comment: The first 2 examples are trying to send objects, not JSON.  You need to use it with both of those.

Comment: I did. Again i get a null json on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on the following changes.

Your JSON Array should look like this :

```
    arr = '[
            {
                "deviceUUID": "lssfds998",
                "os": "bb",
                "pushToken": "l1355436gdfsfdsl"


     }
    ]';

$.ajax
({
     type: "POST",
     url: " DOMAIN/Server_CityInfo/register.php",
     data: {data:arr},
     success : function(result)
     {
         // do something
     }

});
```

And For the Server Side :

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$json = json_decode($data);

// do something with JSON ARRAY
?>
```

Hope this will work. Thanks